# Issue with coroutines fold function and Firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

thank you for taking your time to read my problem.

Im currently using Firebase Firestore to retrieve a **list of objects** that I which to display to the UI, im trying to use a **suspend function to fold the accumulative values** of a sequence of calls from the Firestore server, but at the moment im unable to pass the result value outside the scope of the coroutine.

**This is my fold function:**

```
suspend fun getFormattedList(): FirestoreState {
    return foldFunctions(FirestoreModel(""), ::getMatchesFromBackend, ...., ....)
}
```

**This is my custom fold function:**

```
suspend fun foldFunctions(model: FirestoreModel,
    vararg functions: suspend (FirestoreModel, SuccessData) -> FirestoreState): FirestoreState {

    val successData: SuccessData = functions.fold(SuccessData()) { updatedSuccessData, function ->
            val status = function(model, updatedSuccessData)
            if (status !is FirestoreState.Continue) {
                return status
            }
            updatedSuccessData  <--- I managed to retrieve the list of values correctly here
        }

    val successModel = SuccessData() 
    successData.matchList?.let { successModel.matchList = it } 
    successData.usermatchList?.let { successModel.usermatchList = it } 
    successData.formattedList?.let { successModel.formattedList = it } 

    return FirestoreState.Success(successModel) <--- I cant event get to this line with debugger on
}
```

**This is my first function (which is working fine)**

```
suspend fun getMatchesFromBackend(model: FirestoreModel, successData: SuccessData): FirestoreState {
        return try {
            val querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot? = db.collection("matches").get().await()

            querySnapshot?.toObjects(Match::class.java).let { list ->
                val matchList = mutableListOf<Match>()
                list?.let {
                    for (document in it) {
                        matchList.add(Match(document.away_score,
                            document.away_team,
                            document.date,
                            document.home_score,
                            document.home_team,
                            document.match_id,
                            document.matchpoints,
                            document.played,
                            document.round,
                            document.tournament))
                    }
                    successData.matchList = matchList <--- where list gets stored
                }
            }
            FirestoreState.Continue
        } catch (e : Exception){
            when (e) {
                is RuntimeException -> FirestoreState.MatchesFailure
                is ConnectException -> FirestoreState.MatchesFailure
                is CancellationException -> FirestoreState.MatchesFailure
                else -> FirestoreState.MatchesFailure
            }
        }
    }
```

My hypothesis is that the suspen fun get cancelled and the continuation of the scope gets blocked, I have tried to use **runBlocking { }** without vail. If someone has an idea of how to circumvent this issue I'd be very gratefull.

Comment: Are you sure you never reached a point where if condition is triggered and function returns immediately? Try adding a debugger there.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I bombarded all my code with breakpoints and the only line not being triggered is the return of the fold function, i edit my question to represent that more clearly. Ty